# API or tutorial for the use of x3dom in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If there's no existing tutorial/wiki, then I'm willing to create one. I've seen the d3.js examples of [scatterplot](http://bl.ocks.org/hlvoorhees/5986172), the [3d cubes](http://bl.ocks.org/ZJONSSON/1291667), the awesome [3d svg example](http://christopheviau.com/var/d33d/), [3d force layout](https://vida.io/documents/N4jSip7n68yQ48DXp) and [3d bar graph](http://bl.ocks.org/camio/5087116), but am having a hard time figuring out how to get x3dom syntax translated to d3 syntax.

I've tried making the 3d bar graph an emissive surface like so and it works:

```
shapesEnter
    .append("appearance")
    .append("material")
    //.attr("diffuseColor",  '0.41 0.39 0.03' )
    .attr("emissiveColor", '0.41 0.39 0.03')
    //.attr("ambientIntensity",  '0.0243902' )
    .attr("shininess",  '0.12' )
    .attr("specularColor",  '0.94 0.72 0' );
```

But when trying to [apply textures](http://www.web3d.org/files/specifications/19775-1/V3.2/Part01/components/texturing.html) (after commenting out the above code), it doesn't work:

```
shapesEnter.append("ImageTexture").attr("url", "file:///image1.png").attr("repeatS", "true").attr("repeatT", "true");
```

**My questions are:**
1. About how to figure out the x3dom equivalent syntax in d3?
2. How do I get a texture onto the 3d bar? (objective is to have a colour gradient on the bar, and texture seems to be the only way to do it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 is a library to create and manipulate DOM elements based on data. Other libraries can manipulate DOM elements as well, the difference between D3 and other libraries is that D3 bind data elements to DOM elements. If you have a div with ID `chart`, you can append a `x3d` element to it and set its attributes:

```
var div = d3.select('#chart'),
    chart = div.append('x3d')
        .attr('width', '500px')
        .attr('height', '400px');
```

This will modify the DOM structure of the page:

```
<div id='chart'>
    <x3d width="500px" height="400px"></x3d>
</div>
```

You can append scenes and transformations using the reference to chart:

```
// Create the scene ans transform, and set their attributes
var scene = chart.append('scene'),
    transform = scene.append('transform');
```

Until now, you have just manipulated the DOM, but D3 becomes more interesting when you bind selections to data. Let's say we have an array with the definitions for some shapes:

```
var deg = ['boxShape', 'sphereShape', 'cylinderShape'];

// Create a selection for the shapes that will be created and bind the selection
// to the array of colors
var shapes = transform.selectAll('shape.main-shape')
    .data(colors);

// Append the shapes on enter and set some attributes
shapes.enter().append('shape')
   .attr('class', 'main-shape');

// Update the 'def' attribute of the shapes, using the contents of the bound array
shapes.attr('def', function(d) { return d; });
```

I don't know the details about why the texture is not working, but I would recommend to inspect the generated code using the Web Developer Tools of the browser and see if the generated markup is different that you expect. If you can create a jsFiddle with a simple example, it would be easier to help you with the textures. There is a [great tutorial](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials) on D3 by Scott Murray, to learn the details on data binding and selections. Regards,